# Eclipse Maven Project shows File.not.found exception

Tags: java, java-io

Hi Guys I have created a Maven Project in Eclipse and i have created an file inside `src/Files/CustomerDetails.txt` all i need is to read that file from the `Person.java` Class.  I am facing

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException[enter image description here][1]
```

How should i give my path?

`src/main/java` where i have a package called com.sync
inside that package i have a class called Customer.java where i will read the file which is located at src/Files Folder

Comment: In maven projects, files and other resources should be located in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Hi @IslamEl-Rougy ok then how should i give it as path?

Comment: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("CustomerDetails.txt");`

Comment: Hi @IslamEl-Rougy now i get the following error

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Comment: Try `Customer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("CustomerDetails.txt");`